# Angular rxjs takeUntilDestroyed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Just need some clarification on documentation of takeUntilDestroyed operator, so reading this doc: https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed , I dont see any words that I should use takeUntilDestroyed without params only in "injection" context (I dont really know what does this means). So basicly "Otherwise, the current DestroyRef is injected." so I can use it every where in component, directive, service, etc.

So question is this documentation is not fully describe how injection happens or it is problem with me?

(Please dont put any link explaining how this operator works, I know exactly how it works and checked source code, question is about documentation understanding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injection context is explained in [this doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context). Basically, it's a runtine context where a current injector is set and Angular is able to use for dependency injection.

`takeUntilDestroyed` requires an `DestroyREf` to schedule the observable completion. this can be done 2 ways:

- rely in DI to get it, that the default behaviour and uses `inject(DestroyRef)`. `inject` requires of course an injection context
- Pass `DestroyRef` as argument, so no injection context is required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont see in the doc that I should use takeUntilDestroyed without param inside injection context

Comment: This is what the "Otherwise, the current DestroyRef is injected." part means. `DestroyRef` is injected from the injection context if non is given as argument.

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
class SomeComponent {
  // this is in an injection context
  someService = inject(SomeService);
  destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef)


  constructor() {
    // this is in an injection context

    obs$.pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed() // destroyRef not needed
    ).subscribe(() => {
      ...
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this is NOT in an injection context
  }

  someMethod() {
    // this is NOT in an injection context

    obs$.pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef) // destroyRef needed
    ).subscribe(() => {
      ...
    })
  }
}
```